# Cant reach return statement in a boolean

Tags: boolean

I am trying to reach the second return statement. For whatever reason, the code stops after reaching the first if statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
 function orderFood(food) {
if (true){
return 'chinese';
} 
else if (false){
return 'italian';
   }
  }
   orderFood(false);
```

Comment: try to get familiar with if else https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will never reach to the second statement. The if else statement is expecting a variable whose value to be matched. If you hard coded the true then the else if never be working. I suggest you to understand the basic of if-else.

```
function orderFood(food) {
   //here food is a boolean variable and if else will look for this
   if (food){
       return 'chinese';
   } else{
       return 'italian';
   }
}
```

Comment: I set the function to false, but I am still not reaching the false return.

Comment: have a look on the answer. You are not using the food variable

Comment: When I execute the code, I execute it like this
   orderFood(true)
OR
   orderFood(false)
The food variable is irrelevant for my purposes, I think.

Comment: you want chinese if condition is true and italian if order is false. You are passing the boolean value as parameter so you have to check the variable. your function is expecting the variable food of boolean type.